# Execute with temp variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

While building a SQL script, I want to print the stages progress.

I started with :

```
declare @currentStage VARCHAR(10) = 1
declare @totalStages VARCHAR(10) = 10
```

but instead of adding after every step:

```
print 'stage '+@currentStage+'/'+@totalStages+' completed.'
set @currentStage+=1
```

(for printing 'stage 1/10 completed.' and increasing the current stage value)

I would like to put it in string variable, something like this:

```
DECLARE @printAndIncrease as NVARCHAR(500) = 
'
PRINT ''stage ''+@currentStage+''/''+@totalStages+'' completed.''
SET @currentStage += 1
'
```

and execute it every step:

```
EXEC @printAndIncrease
```

but it doesn't works.

I'm open to ideas .... thanks!

Comment: You would need to use `sp_executesql` and pass the variables in as parameters. And by the time you've done that it will probably be no shorter than just copying and pasting the PRINT (though would allow you to change the string in one place)

Comment: You *could* create a stored procedures where you pass the variables and where @currentstage is an input/output variable, so you can increment it inside the procedure. As others said, not sure it's worth the hassle

Comment: Though actually you could just use `RAISERROR` and string interpolation for this use case anyway https://dbfiddle.uk/kC0fCXlz

Comment: @Zhorov , i also tried with parentheses, same results

Comment: thank you guys, i probably skip it.. i just tried to clean up the code and shorting it.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use `sys.sp_executesql` and pass in the variables as parameters so it can access them (remembering to make `@currentStage` an `output` parameter as that is written to).

[Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/2d4e2WLk).

```
declare @currentStage INT = 1;
declare @totalStages INT = 10;

DECLARE @printAndIncreaseSql as NVARCHAR(500) = '
PRINT CONCAT(''stage '',@currentStage,''/'',@totalStages,'' completed.'');
SET @currentStage += 1;
'
  
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @printAndIncreaseSql, N'@totalStages INT, @currentStage INT OUTPUT', @totalStages,  @currentStage output;

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @printAndIncreaseSql, N'@totalStages INT, @currentStage INT OUTPUT', @totalStages,  @currentStage output;
```

I'd probably not bother and use something like

```
declare @currentStage INT = 1;
declare @totalStages INT = 10;
declare @progressString nvarchar(1000) = 'stage %d/%d completed.';

RAISERROR (@progressString,0,1, @currentStage, @totalStages) WITH NOWAIT; set @currentStage+=1;

RAISERROR (@progressString,0,1, @currentStage, @totalStages) WITH NOWAIT; set @currentStage+=1;
```